# How to customize JMeter reports in maven to show Pass-Fail instead of OK-KO/add more static values in the report?

Tags: maven, jmeter

I have multiple jmx files which are committed to gitpipeline for CI. End users are not fine with reports showing OK/KO and requested us to change the same and also asked us to add few details like total time take for the execution, description of the test and environment/hostname used.

Solutions am looking for -

1. how to change OK/KO when the JMX is executed **using maven**. What properties do i need to change/add in order to achieve this for maven?
2. Is there a way to customize the report to have additional details like "Total Duration", "Environment", "Description of Test" under Test and Report information section or anywhere else?
3. If it is not achievable using the default report available, are there ***any other JMeter report plugin's for maven***?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As of [JMeter 5.2.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-1-released-td5728641.html) the `KO` and `OK` labels are not controllable by any JMeter properties, you will have to go into [/bin/report-template/content/js/dashboard.js.fmkr](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.2.1/bin/report-template/content/js/dashboard.js.fmkr#L139) and change the labels there
2. Similarly for extra columns, you will need to add them manually in the aforementioned file.

Get familiarized with [Apache FreeMarker](https://freemarker.apache.org/) template engine, this is what JMeter is using under the hood in order to produce the dashboard.

Alternatively you can consider a 3rd-party results analysis solution like [BM.Sense](https://sense.blazemeter.com/) which reports test duration out of the box and provides possibility to add comments to the execution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Dmitri, however my question was "**how to get different labels when i use it via maven**". I tried by placing the locally generated "**dashboard.js.fmkr**" under "_${project.build.directory}/jmeter/testFiles_" and "_${project.base.directory}/src/test/conf_" - it didn't work.

Comment: can you look if this can be done for maven? sorry! am in need of this to close and hence sending this reminder

Comment: You will be in position to tell me what to do and send reminders when I'll be your employee and this is never gonna happen. As an exception and a new year present I'll give you a hint: make a copy of `report-template` folder, perform the customization, and [point JMeter Maven Plugin to this folder](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Modifying-Properties#5) with the customized template via [`jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.property.template_dir` JMeter Property.](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/)